# Enthought Canopy: Opening a file in web browser

Tags: python, terminal, enthought, canopy

My professor told me to download Enthought Canopy, then he showed me some files he was editing online and wanted me to take a look at them. He did this using the terminal. I'm pretty sure he just went into the terminal, typed python, then something else, then a file automatically popped up in the web browser. I can't remember what command he used and have searched online and came up with nothing. Would anybody know how to do this? Thanks!

(and yes I have the file name)

Comment: I would advise asking your professor.

Comment: Well I was hoping I wouldn't have to embarass myself doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the simplest way to do this is to invoke the webbrowser package from the standard library:

```
from webbrowser import open_new
open_new("http://www.google.com")
open_new("file://<YOUR FILE PATH HERE>")
```

HTH,